# MPMusicPlayerController queue issues

Tags: ios, mpmediaitemcollection, mpmediaplayercontroller

I'm having some issues with my MPMusicPlayerController. It's an an iPodMusicPlayer, not an appmusicplayer. My problem is that I can not get the queue to play in the correct order. Let me explain further:

I use an iPod picker to select a media collection, which I then add to the music player's queue. Once i do this, I display the items in the collection on a table view. A user can then "play" this queue. However, for some reason when I try to navigate thru the playlist with the ipod controls, the queue seems like its in the incorrect order. Here is some code:

The media picker calls this method:

```
-(void)updatePlayerQueueWithMediaCollection:(MPMediaItemCollection *)collection {

if (collection) {

    // If there's no playback queue yet...

    if (self.userMediaItemCollection == nil) {
        [self setUserMediaItemCollection: collection];
        [self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:self.userMediaItemCollection];
    } else {
        BOOL wasPlaying = NO;
        if (self.musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
            wasPlaying = YES;
        }

        // Save the now-playing item and its current playback time.

        MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem        = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
        NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime = self.musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;

        // Combine the previously-existing media item collection with the new one

        NSMutableArray *combinedMediaItems =
        [[self.userMediaItemCollection items] mutableCopy];
        NSArray *newMediaItems = [collection items];
        [combinedMediaItems addObjectsFromArray: newMediaItems];

        [self setUserMediaItemCollection:[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:(NSArray *) combinedMediaItems]];

        [self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: self.userMediaItemCollection];

        // Restore the now-playing item and its current playback time.

        self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem      = nowPlayingItem;
        self.musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = currentPlaybackTime;

        if (wasPlaying) {
            [self.musicPlayer play];
        }
    }
}
int i = 0; 
for (MPMediaItem *item in [self.userMediaItemCollection items]){
    NSLog(@"playback queue item %i has title %@",i, [item valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] );
    i++;
}
```

}

simple enough, this is taken directly from apple. That NSLog at the bottom logs out the queue and it appears correct.

From here a user can click a play button to play the queue. I set that up like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setNowPlayingItem:)]) {
    NSArray *items = [[MusicPlayerManager sharedMusicPlayer].userMediaItemCollection items];
    [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setNowPlayingItem:) withObject:[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setTrackList:)]) {
    [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setTrackList:) withObject:[MusicPlayerManager sharedMusicPlayer].userMediaItemCollection];
    NSLog(@"tracklist from tltbvc looks like %@", [MusicPlayerManager sharedMusicPlayer].userMediaItemCollection);
}
```

}

In the destination view controller, the setNowPlayingItem method looks like this:

```
-(void) setNowPlayingItem:(MPMediaItem *)nowPlayingItem {
    _nowPlayingItem = nowPlayingItem;
    [MusicPlayerManager sharedMusicPlayer].musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem = nowPlayingItem;
    [[MusicPlayerManager sharedMusicPlayer].musicPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"index of now playing item %i", [[MusicPlayerManager sharedMusicPlayer].musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem]);
}
```

This plays the correct song from the tableview indexpath, but for some reason the index no longer matches its location in the table. If the song in row index 0 is ABC, the player plays ABC but logs out an indexOfNowPlayingItem that is no longer 0. When i try to skip forward and back, the order from the queue is no longer maintained. I have no idea whats going on

Any help greatly appreciated, and sorry to include so much code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wow for some reason it had shuffle set to on. Thats embarassing. this fixed everything:

```
    sharedMusicPlayer.musicPlayer.shuffleMode = MPMusicShuffleModeOff;
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for ending my two hour headache by not deleting this question.